# Вопросительное ЧТО в сложных предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, местоимения, вопрос

Рассмотрим два предложения

```
1. У них там что, других сюжетов не бывает?
2. Что, у них там других сюжетов не бывает?
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это двухосновные, сложные предложения? Корректно ли на основании этого использовать альтернативную пунктуацию

```
У них там, что, других сюжетов не бывает?
```

Возможно ли местоимение **что** заменить на новомодную вопросительную частицу **чё** и на основании этого не ставить запятую

```
Чё других сюжетов не бывает?
```

или это будет трактоваться по старинке не как частица, а как местоимение:

```
Чё, других сюжетов не бывает?
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет сложных предложений. Слово «что» не всегда является союзным словом(ужасный термин, так как любой союз это слово). В приведенных вами предложениях «что», «чё» можно убрать без изменения смысла предложения: «У них там других сюжетов не бывает?» В этих предложениях слово «что» не является союзным словом или местоимением, а выполняет некую тонкую специфическую функцию в речи. Какую? Мне лень разбираться. Нужно рассмотреть пару десятков предложений и попытаться уловить то, почему люди добавляют это «что» в таких вопросах.
Функция примерно следующая: в русском языке мы понимаем, что это вопрос, только по интонации и контексту, и данное слово помогает отчетливо обозначить то, что это вопрос, что может быть не совсем понятно в определенных ситуациях, особенно на письме(есть вопросительный знак, но будет легкое недопонимание, пока мы не дочитаем до конца предложения).

Comment: Вам следует избегать таких длинных предложений (это по поводу последнего абзаца).

Comment: Да, все примерно так. Для меня интересно то, как официальный синтаксис (преподаватели и любители со стажем) переваривает это казалось бы несущественное "что". Ведь для него оно как кость в горле. И я думаю, это не союзное слово. Знатоки поправят.

Answer (score 0):

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1689-1705.html

> Частицы **что, что ли, а, как** относятся к разговорной, непринужденной
> речи. Частица что или открывает собою вопросительное предложение, или
> следует за вынесенным в начало предложения именем: Что, он опять
> опаздывает?; Он что, опять опаздывает? Частица что выражает также
> переспрос ( - Ты меня слышишь? - Что?). Частица что ли, вносящая
> оттенок фамильярности, обычно заключает собою предложение (Заснул что
> ли?; Опять скандал, что ли?), но может и открывать его. Эта частица
> очень часто употребляется вместе с частицей что; они обрамляют
> предложение (Что, заснул, что ли?; Что, опять скандал, что ли?).
> Частица а заключает собою вопрос; она вносит значение побуждения к
> ответу (Пойдем, а?) или выражает переспрос (- Пойди сюда. - А?).
> Частица как имеет собственно вопросительное значение: Как (ну как),
> согласен?; при переспросе: - Я не пойду. - Как? Как не пойдешь? (Как
> это?; Как это (не пойду)?).

Тогда такой вопрос, можем ли мы считать "что" не частицей, а членом сложного предложения?

```
Он что, опять опаздывает? = Он что? Опять опаздывает?
Что, устал, а? = Что? Устал, а?
```